# 24h problems in convertDateTime in JSF

Tags: jsf, time, converters

I have an input textfield with a convertDateTime to see if the time is right. The problem is that convertDateTime is set to 12 hours of counting but I want 24 hours of counting, someone who knows how to solve this?

If for example, I type in 14:12, I get the error message: '14: 12 'could not be under stood as a date.
But 02:12 is fine.

Here is the code:

```
<h:outputText value="Time"/>

<h:inputText value="#{backBean.time}" >
 <f:convertDateTime type="time" pattern="hh:mm" timeZone="#{backBean.timeZone}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Backbean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "backBean")
@SessionScoped
public class BackBean {

 private Date date = new Date();

 public void setTime(Date inDate)
{
    date.setMinutes(inDate.getMinutes());
    date.setHours(inDate.getHours());
 }

public Date getTime()
{
   return date;
  }

public TimeZone getTimeZone() {  
  TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();  
  return timeZone;  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `<f:convertDateTime>` uses [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API under the covers, whose javadoc is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), listing all available pattern letters.

For hours, you used a pattern of `hh` which is in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) described as

```
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)
```

, while you clearly want the one described as follows in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)
```

Fix it accordingly:

```
<f:convertDateTime type="time" pattern="HH:mm" timeZone="#{backBean.timeZone}"/>
```

Comment: aha it were that simple, thanks for the help! I was close to breaking down there for a while.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code no need to hit the Managedbeans

```
<h:outputText value="Time"/>

<h:inputText value="#{backBean.time}" >

<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MMM-yy 'at' hh:mm aa" />

</h:inputText>
```